# How do I measure frozen herbs, like dried or fresh?

Tags: herbs

I froze a lot of my herbs over the summertime, but now I'm not sure how to measure them for my recipes....Do I measure as fresh or dried?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely as fresh. And you might want to add a little more to compensate for the flavours lost in the freezing process.